# Compare Laplace, second order nonhomogenous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

What other methods besides Laplace can be used to solve second order non homogenous diff eq? When would you choose to use or not use Laplace?

Comment: See this as an example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428593/how-can-i-solve-this-linear-differential-equation-y-prime-prime-4y-prime

Comment: @Tonya: Matrix methods, variation of parameters, Reduction of order, Laplace Transforms, Undetermined Coefficients, Series Solutions, ... I think the method of solution is sometimes dependant on what works and sometimes what you are comfortable with and sometimes guessing! Whatever works, so which is better is not really answerable.

Comment: It depends on what the diff eq _is_... and if it's linear you usually have a lot of options to choose from, whereas if it's not your possibilities are going to be more limited